# Setting blurAmount to a state / variable in @reactnativecommunity/blur causing app to crash

Tags: react-native, expo

I want my main view to blue when the user hits submit. The blur works if it is a provided string but when a state or variable is used to set the blurAmount, the app crashes. I am using expo version 49 ejected using npx expo run:android. How do I fix this? Code is below:

```
const [isBlurred, setIsBlurred] = useState(false);
.....
<BlurView
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          right: 0,
        }}
        blurType="light"
        blurAmount={isBlurred ? "10" : "0"}
        reducedTransparencyFallbackColor="white"
      />
```